# Upload a file to URL from command line

Tags: command-line, wget, upload

We can download a file using the following command line in Ubuntu:

```
wget url
```

Can anyone tell me how to upload file to URL?

Comment: You can't simply 'upload' a file to the web, you have to use something to do it e.g. an Ftp server. What is your purpose?

Comment: Try `wput` the counterpart of `wget`^^

Comment: Check the manual page for rcp scp sftp.

Comment: please edit your question to include the full URL you are trying to upload to, including the "http://", "ftp://" etc.

Comment: @KasiyA Please,  ask a new question, don't hijack someone else's (a bad one at that).

Comment: @Seth But it's the same as what I want :(

Comment: @KasiyA No it isn't.  You had to edit it and change it to make it what you want.  This question isn't salvageable.

Comment: @Seth But helpers [wants url](http://askubuntu.com/questions/397801/upload-a-file-to-url-from-command-line?noredirect=1#comment509818_397801)

Comment: @KasiyA Exactly,  which is why this question is terrible. You can't tell what the OP really wanted so you can't edit it without completely changing the question. Please, just ask a new one,  this one isn't worth the time and effort to salvage in that way.

Comment: @Seth Owwwkeeey